# Что значит T extends SuperClass?

Tags: java

Что в **java** означает такая конструкция (объявление класса):

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass<T extends SuperAbstractClass & IMyInterface>{
...
}
```

Во-первых что значит конструкция `MyAbstractClass<T extends SuperAbstractClass>`, чем она отличается от `MyAbstractClass extends SuperAbstractClass`?

Во вторых смущает **& IMyInterface**, как это понимать? Наследут класс и Имплементит интерфейс?

Answer (score 3):

Это означает, что класс **MyAbstractClass** генерифицирован(generified - не знаю, как точно по-русски) с помощью типа **T**. Ключевое слово **extends** означает, что этот тип **Т** должен быть наследником класса **SuperAbstractClass** и реализовывать интерфейс **IMyInterface**.

По дженерикам советую почитать отличную книгу [«Java Generics and Collections»](http://www.amazon.com/Java-Generics-Collections-Maurice-Naftalin/dp/0596527756) (авторы: Maurice Naftalin и Philip Wadler).

Comment: По-русски это называется "обобщенный класс".

Answer (score 1):

Здесь абстрактный класс параметризован `MyAbstractClass` параметризован типом `T`. Здесь под `T` должен быть экземпляр класса, расширяющий `SuperAbstractClass` и одновременно реализующий интерфейс `IMyInterface`. Получается объявление класса объекта, переданного в параметры должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
class класс extends SuperAbstractClass implements IMyInterface {
// Код.
}
```